# What percentage of questions posted here are also on-topic on Cross Validated and Data Science?

Tags: discussion

Has anyone tried to approximate the percentage of questions posted here that are also on-topic on Cross Validated and Data Science?

Comment: Except reinforcement learning and algorithm or conceptual questions pretty much all...based on my experience I would say 90-95%...but recently questions about RL is increasing.

Comment: @DuttaA Reinforcement leaning is also on topic on   Cross Validated and Data Science. I agree with the 90-95% estimate.